# Duvida em porcentagem em C

Tags: c

O usuário tem que dar um valor que seria o preço do produto
e um valor que seria o desconto

Na hora de dar o valor final eu não consigo
já tentei algumas coisas

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    float preco, desc, end;
    printf("Qual o valor da compra? ");
    scanf("%f", &preco);

    printf("Qual o valor do desconto? ");
    scanf("%f", &desc);

    end = preco / desc;
    printf("O valor final e: %f", end);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte maneira.
Descontando 10% no valor de R$30,00 temos: 
30 * 0,90 = R$27,00
end = preco * porcentagem_do_desconto;

para acréscimos basta que o valor da porcentagem esteja dessa maneira "30 * 1.10"

Answer (score 1):

O cálculo correto do valor com desconto é:

```
end = preco - ( preco * desc / 100 );
```

considerando que `desc` é o valor do desconto (em porcento) entre 0 e 100.

Answer (score 1):

Sua fórmula para o calculo de desconto está errada, nesse caso, como você quer descontar o valor você precisa subtrair o preço pela multiplicação do preço pelo valor da porcentagem.
Nesse caso o seu código ficará assim:

```c
int main ()
{
    float preco, desc;
    printf("Qual o valor da compra? ");
    scanf("%f", &preco);

    printf("Qual o valor do desconto? ");
    scanf("%f", &desc);

    printf("O valor final e: %.2f", preco - (preco * desc/100));
}
```

A saída ficará assim:

```
Qual o valor da compra? 10
Qual o valor do desconto? 5
O valor final e: 9.50
```

Note que retirei a variável `end` pois voce não precisa dela. Espero ter ajudado :)